# Copying from Azure file to BLOB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Does Azure have a way of moving files between Storage containers without downloading it back down to your laptop? I tried AzCopy but that seems to be downloading then re-uploading the file.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to provision some compute in Azure to do that. For example you could provision a small VM and run AzCopy in there. Or you could deploy something to Azure batch. Or you might even be able to use Azure Data Factory to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage

Comment: Azure Data Factory is another option that would work. Do note that A.D.F. carries a much higher cost than the VM option.

Comment: Copying blobs between storage containers is an async server side operation and it does not require you to download and reupload. AzCopy supports this. I am surprised when you say that AzCopy is downloading and re-uploading the file. Can you share how you're using AzCopy?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Azcopy does not necessarily require a compute piece, see my answer.

Comment: So basically the assumption of the questioner was incorrect. (As was mine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azcopy does indeed provide the feature for [server-side copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#synccopy). It is in fact the default behaviour.
You can find an example of that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#copy-a-single-blob-from-one-storage-account-to-another):
`AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key /DestKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt`

However, be warned: As you are getting the required compute basically for free as spare capacity from Azure, you do not get any performance SLA. So this is most cases way slower than for example using a fast VM in the same Azure region and using what's called synchronous copy (down- and upload to copy, using the `/SyncCopy` parameter in azcopy).

So: If you have time and what to save money, use server-side copy. If you want your copy to be done quickly, use /SyncCopy

Comment: That's great to know. Your answer is in fact far more detailed and specific than the original question!

Comment: Ok got it. Yeah I found it was very slow hence why I assumed it must be copying to my laptop first. And the use of a VM makes sense. I personally think movement between Azure storage should be seen as a fundamental capability that's better supported within the Azure web portal itself.

Comment: Note that Azcopy is very compute-intensive. To optimize performance, it will use all the CPU power it can get. So if you want to have a really fast copy, use a VM SKU with good CPU power and Accelerated Networking (e.g. something like a F32s_v2)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-creating-importing-runbook) to accomplish this. Here is link to an article on Microsoft's site that accomplishes this;

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/05/09/azure-storage-account-backup-azure-automation-runbook-azure-functions/

here is the relevant code, slightly modified to make ResourceGroup a variable.

```
$primary = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'Log-Storage-Primary'
$secondary = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'Log-Storage-Secondary'
$ResourceGroupName = Get-AutomatioNVariable -Name 'LogStorageResourceGroup'

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$primarykey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $primary
$secondarykey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $secondary

$primaryctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $primary -StorageAccountKey $primarykey.Key1
$secondaryctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $secondary -StorageAccountKey $secondarykey.Key1

$primarycontainers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $primaryctx

# Loop through each of the containers
foreach($container in $primarycontainers) {
    # Do a quick check to see if the secondary container exists, if not, create it.
    $secContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $container.Name -Context $secondaryctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (!$secContainer) {
        $secContainer = New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $secondaryctx -Name $container.Name
        Write-Host "Successfully created Container" $secContainer.Name "in Account" $secondary
    }

    # Loop through all of the objects within the container and copy them to the same container on the secondary account
    $primaryblobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $primaryctx
    foreach($blob in $primaryblobs) {
        $copyblob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $secondaryctx -Blob $blob.Name -Container $container.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # Check to see if the blob exists in the secondary account or if it has been updated since the last runtime.
        if (!$copyblob -or $blob.LastModified -gt $copyblob.LastModified) {
            $copyblob = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcBlob $blob.Name -SrcContainer $container.Name -Context $primaryctx -DestContainer $secContainer.Name -DestContext $secondaryctx -DestBlob $blob.Name
            $status = $copyblob | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState

            while ($status.Status -eq "Pending") {
                $status = $copyblob | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState
                Start-Sleep 10
            }
            Write-Host "Successfully copied blob" $copyblob.Name "to Account" $secondary "in container" $container.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do all this complicated stuff. Using Azure Storage SDK for .Net (or any other language for that matter) should do the trick.